# c# storing data in xml - how to read and write to it

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am in the process of creating a program for assigning shifts in a rota/schedule and up until now I've been using a hard coded class which contains the records for the people in it.

I'm now looking to store the data properly and was thinking xml could be a good way to do this.

I have a class `Person` which contains the info for the person and a class `MyDataSource` which creates 5 instances of the `Person` class and stores them in a list which I can add or remove to.

I've been looking at using the sterilization to read and write the xml files but am struggling to understand it.

Should I be able to add the code to my existing `Person` class or do I need to create a separate class to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;


namespace ShiftSorter
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int hours { get; set; }
        public int row { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of the object Person.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newName">The name of the person</param>
        public Person(string newName)
        {
            name = newName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL! Sterilization sure is a novel and unusual way of storing data. I think you might have meant "serialization" ;)

Comment: To persist your data you can also use a local database. You would have more control on your data. Follow this link to learn more about LocalDB https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx

Comment: Haha dammed auto-correct! Yes I don't think sterilization will get me very far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Your class should be Serializable:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[Serializable]
public class Person { }
```

Secondly, You need to create empty constructor, just for XML parsing:

```
// Default constructor for serialization
public Person() { }
```

From now, every public field will be serialized-deserialized by methods:

```
private void Serialize()
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.xml", FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(typeof(Person));
        serializer.Serialize(fs, this);
    }
}

public static Person Deserialize(string filename = "person.xml")
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(typeof(Person));
        return (Person)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    }
}
```

You can create class from file by:

```
Person person = Person.Deserialize("person.xml");
```

Comment: Tried it and worked great, replaced the "person.xml" with name + ".xml" too so the files are saved as the persons name, just need to add some validation to make sure the name doesn't contain any awkward characters. Thanks for the help